# Sikuli: Multiple icon sorting

Tags: python, image, sorting, sikuli

**Objective:** To click all "stars" in a page by moving through the row first and then columns in **Sikuli**

**Example:** The stars are arranged in a grid like so:

```
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

**EDIT :** This is the order to be clicked:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

First click the one on the top-left then the star on its right and so on. Next go to the top-left star on the second row and repeat.

My current code:

```
def by_x(match):
    return match.x
def by_y(match):
    return match.y
stars = findAll("imgOfStar")
sorted_stars_x = sorted(stars, key=by_x)
sorted_stars_y = sorted(stars, key=by_y)
for icon in sorted_stars_x:
    for icon2 in sorted_stars_y:
        click("imgOfStar")
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant way, but it's the first thing I could think of:

```
def by_y(match):
    return match.y
stars = findAll(imageOfStars)
sorted_stars_y = sorted(stars, key=by_y)
finalStars = []
count = 0
for x in range(5): #if you know your grid is 5x5
    finalStars.append(sorted(sorted_stars_y[count:count + 5])) #see explanation, if needed
    count += 5
for x in finalStars:
    click(x)
```

explanation:  the first five stars from your example should have matching y values, i.e. they should all be the top row. So now, you're just sorting their x value, and appending them to a list, then moving on to the next five, and so on.

If the size of your grid is not known before hand, you could accomplish this a few different ways--
If your grid is always perfectly square, you could find the square root of your number of stars:

```
 import math #or import sqrt from math, if the square root is the only math function you need.
 def by_y(match):
    return match.y
stars = findAll(imageOfStars)
sorted_stars_y = sorted(stars, key=by_y)
finalStars = []
count = 0
rows = math.sqrt(len(stars))
for x in range(rows):
    finalStars.append(sorted(sorted_stars_y[count:count + rows]))
    count += rows
```

If your grid is not perfectly square, there are some other things you can do, but unless that is what you are looking for, this answer has become a bit long, so we'll save that discussion for later :)

EDIT:
Since you know your number of columns is always 5, you could find the number of rows like this:

```
 rows = (len(stars) / 5)
 rowCount = 0
 count = 0
```

Then you can use a while loop to iterate through your stars:

```
while rowCount < rows:
    finalStars.append(sorted(sorted_Stars_y[count:count+ 5]))
    count += 5
    rowCount += 1
```

After all is said and done, this will get the job done for you, but the answer from @Tenzin is more elegant :)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. But I don't know the number of rows. I only know the number of columns, which is 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a a definition where you make clear how you like to move through the stars. 
The screen itself has a x.y position. To start at the Top-Left and end at the Bottom-Right you need
match.y, match.x.

Then you need to findAll("stars.png") the stars. 
Those stars you go sorting, in the order you defined.

Then you use a for loop to do something with the stars.

Example code:

```
class Stars():
     def order(match):
          return match.y, match.x
     # Find all icons 
     icons = findAll("stars.png")
     # Sort all the stars. 
     sorted_icons = sorted(icons, key=order)
     # Click on every star. 
     for icon in sorted_icons:
          click(icon)
```